# how to fix EntityValidationErrors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I want to update user but whene I click on submit I get this error : EntityValidationErrors in this ligne : 
Ligne 335 :                context.SaveChanges();

I am using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC project:

this this my edit action in controller :

```
// GET: ApplicationUsers/Edit/2 : 
     [AuthLog(Roles = "Super Administrateur")]
    public ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    // POST: ApplicationUsers/Edit/2 
    [AuthLog(Roles = "Super Administrateur")]
    [HttpPost, ValidateInput(false), ActionName("Edit")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,No_,RaisonSociale,Magasin,RemiseHabituelle,FamilyName,FirstName,EmailSup,Login,AffPrix,PasserCmd,EmailRespMagasin,Admin,BoursePR,Actif,IdSession,VendeurItirénant,ChargeClient,ValidOuAnnul,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ListUsers","Account");
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```

this is the Edit View :

```
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Login, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Login, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Remember reading *If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer*, and making the promise *I will keep these tips in mind when asking* by checking a checkbox?

Comment: thanks for replying me Gert Arnold , I will update my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

The solution was : that UserName attributes is required.I find this error by adding block try {} catch {} to my edit action :

```
  public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,No_,RaisonSociale,Magasin,RemiseHabituelle,FamilyName,FirstName,EmailSup,Login,AffPrix,PasserCmd,EmailRespMagasin,Admin,BoursePR,Actif,IdSession,VendeurItirénant,ChargeClient,ValidOuAnnul,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
             catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
          {
             Exception raise = dbEx;
              foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                  foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                  {   string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                          validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                         validationError.ErrorMessage);
                      // raise a new exception nesting
                      // the current instance as InnerException
                      raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                  }
            }
              throw raise;
         }
            return RedirectToAction("ListUsers","Account");
        }
        return View(applicationUser);
    }
```